# Forcing "snap-to-road" when reshaping a line via basemap reference in ArcGIS desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, polyline-creation

Sometimes, when I use "reshape a feature" in concert with a basemap, I'll find that the resultant line doesn't automatically snap to roads if a pair of verticies are far apart:

[image]

But at the same time, having to place closely spaced vertices along twisty roads is a pain.

[image]

Is there a balance that can be struck when it comes to ArcGIS's snap-to-road tolerance? Or do I just have to suck it up and put in closely-spaced vertices as the only way to guarantee that the resultant line will trace the path that I want?

Comment: Does tracing work with your basemap? it's a lot quicker than re-digitizing. You could try changing to classic snapping, setting the snap tolerance to something larger (Editor::Snapping::options) and make sure the units are pixels and not map units.. in classic snapping you can control which layers are snappable and which location (boundary, vertex and/or edge) can be snapped. If your snap tolerance is too large you will find that it's difficult to snap to an edge as the snap will be the next vertex.. the snaps hierarchy in order: End, Vertex and finally Edge.